# Discontinous vertical lines in table

Tags: tables

I was drawing a table with extra spacing between the rows. Here is my code

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
$\alpha$ & $< -1 $ & $=-1$ & $>-1$ \\
\hline
\\[-1em]
$\int_0^1 x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & D & D & C \\[0.5ex]
\hline
\\[-1em]
$\int_1^{+\infty} x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & C & D & D \\[0.5ex]
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image: table]

As you can see there are discontinuous vertical lines. Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not specifying all columns in the “empty” rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
$\alpha$ & $< -1 $ & $=-1$ & $>-1$ \\
\hline
&&&\\[-1em]
$\int_0^1 x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & D & D & C \\[0.5ex]
\hline
&&&\\[-1em]
$\int_1^{+\infty} x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & C & D & D \\[0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible improvement, without the useless vertical rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\dd}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
 & $\alpha< -1 $ & $\alpha=-1$ & $\alpha>-1$ \\
\midrule
$\displaystyle\int_0^1 x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & D & D & C \\
\addlinespace
$\displaystyle\int_1^{+\infty} x^\alpha \dd{x}$ & C & D & D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`\\[-1em]` adds a blank line, breaking all the rules with `\baselineskip` of space and the backs up by `1em` so will more or less randomly overprint the previous line or leave a gap, depending on the relative sizes of 1em and `\baselineskip`.

`\\` should only ever be use before `\hline` not after.

To increase the spacing below the `\hline` you could increase `\arraystretch` or use

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
```

which requires the `array` package.

Also tables usually look better without vertical lines, which would make the problem of the gaps go away as well.